# Ayuda con armar un query en Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla llamada `ESTRUCTURA` que tiene los campos

```
ID_ESTRUCTURA, NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR, ACTIVO
```

Y una tabla que se llama `TRABAJADOR_RANGO`que tiene los campos

```
ID_TRABAJADOR_RANGO, ID_ESTRUCTURA, ID_SERVICIO, TIPO_RANGO
```

Lo que yo  quiero es mostrar el nombre del trabajador  que son **RESPONSABLES** y el nombre del trabajador que son **SUPLENTES** de un servicio en especifico,

el campo `TIPO RANGO` , puede tener los valores 1 o 2, 
donde 1 = RESPONSABLE  y
 2 = SUPLENTE

y esta es mi consulta

```html
SELECT E.NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR RESPONSABLE, E.NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR SUPLENTE
FROM TABLE_ESTRUCTURA  E, TABLE_TRABAJADOR_RANGO R
WHERE E.ID_ESTRUCTURA = R.ID_ESTRUCTURA
AND R.ID_SERVICIO = 2019
```

y me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se muestra dos registros ya que ese servicio tiene RESPONSABLE Y SUPLENTE, pero repite el mismo nombre, y lo que yo quiero es que salga de esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo hacer para que salga como yo quiero? 
que me pinte **RESPONSABLE** Y **SUPLENTE**

se puede hacer una subconsulta?
donde primero haga algo asi, buscar el nombre del RESPONSABLE y después otro select pero con TIPO_RANGO =2?

```html
SELECT E.NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR RESPONSABLE
FROM TABLE_ESTRUCTURA  E, TABLE_TRABAJADOR_RANGO R
WHERE E.ID_ESTRUCTURA = R.ID_ESTRUCTURA
AND R.ID_SERVICIO = 2019
AND R.TIPO_RANGO = 1
```

o quedaria con GROUP BY?

Ojala me puedan ayuda, no se mucho de BD

Comment: y ya intentaste un `GROUP BY E.NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR` ?agregalo y dinos que te resultó

Comment: Ya lo probé con el group by como lo mencionas, pero sigue apareciendo repetido el nombre

Comment: Revisa la parte de las bases de datos relacionales, la parte de relaciones muchos a muchos. Tal vez tengas que crear una tabla intermedia.